# Ubuntu 14.04 randomly freezes on Dell Precision M4500

Tags: graphics, 14.04, freeze

I know this has been asked several times, but many of them are tagged as duplicates and sent back to what should I do if the computer freezes.  I don't want the computer to freeze and only want those methods as a last resort, not something I have to do every time I boot up!

I am dual booting and Windows works fine.  I was wondering if perhaps it was trying to do something with the nVidia driver on the comp? (It's a Dell Precision M4500 laptop). It just happens to randomly freeze sometimes, no idea what causes it. It just froze when reading an article online (not taxing the system at all). It also froze once when I shut the lid to the laptop and only the mouse was working.

It has frozen several other times as well. Is there perhaps a driver I should install (I have no idea where I would get that) or something else? I would really like to fix this without having to disable the graphics card and "knowing" how to restart it when it freezes.  As I said before I know their are several other posts similar to this, but I didnt see any that really helped me all that much.

Edit: After installing the "current nVidia driver" from the Ubuntu Software Center it has been running very smoothly and I have not had any freezing issues.  If anybody is having the same problem you should definitely try this.  Thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: Thank you! Installing nVidia "current" on Ubuntu 14.04 running on a crappy old Dell Precision 4500 fixed the crashing problem. Prior to this, it was freezing/crashing every 10-15 min.

Comment: I have a Precision M4500 and have the same issue using 17.10 and newer 18.04 as well.  The difference is that when I use the NVIDIA driver, I get a black screen after login in., so I was wondering if someone else out there with a Precision M4500 has the same issue. For more details about my issue, follow this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025393/ubuntu-17-10-and-18-04-beta-2-display-driver-issues-freezing-black-screen-after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and at first I had this problem. I installed nVIDIA driver on My Ubuntu and it has never freeze since I install nVIDIA driver on it.
nVIDIA driver is available in Ubuntu Software Center.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I will definitely try this for sure.  Im just going to install the one that says current, is that what you did?

Comment: Yes. I did this.

Comment: Installing nvidia driver may not fix the problem, as it was for me. Also try `apt-get remove bumblebee-nvidia` that saves the planet.

Answer (score -2):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running on Dell Inspiron 17R. I also had same freeze problem of terminal due to inactivity or even after locking. But I finally got a solution.

Follow the steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> at least 2 times. Wait for some time. You will see login screen.
2. Log in as root.
3. Run command: `reboot`
4. When Ubuntu reboots, select Advanced Setup Options while, using the arrow keys.
5. It will take you to recovery mode.
6. Run in recovery mode.
7. It will prompt to boot as normal boot.
8. Press OK. And it will solve the problem forever.