# ubuntu 16.04. pc Freezes for unknown reason

Tags: 16.04, ssd, freeze

I've just installed ubuntu 16.04 lts and few applications. For some unknown reason my pc freezes. Sometimes when i log in into my social network account through chromium, sometimes when i open video file, sometime when i run application. So when i do something (open/load etc.) there is a chance that my pc freeze.
When it "freezes" screen becomes blank brown or black colored.
How can i find the reason of all this? Does ubuntu have any logs that capture this?
P.S. i've cheched ram several times with memtest86+, checked my hdd (i have 120Gb SSD for ubuntu). I didn't install any non standart drivers or so on.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Most of times it is because lack of installation of Graphic card and lack of compatibility of (at least) UBUNTU with Nvidia VGAs. try to install your VGA driver. [take a look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/467894/ubuntu-14-04-randomly-freezes-on-dell-precision-m4500/467903#467903), If you use Nvidia Graphic card [you can see this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics) too.