# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes or hangs for unknown reason

Tags: 16.04, freeze

I ask this question after 3 months continue observation of my system.
I'm facing a problem with a fresh Ubuntu installation.

#### Problem

1. Ubuntu hangs without any reason, showing no error message.
2. Sometimes Ubuntu works very well and do any heavy work very effective. ex. Video Editing etc, the freezing is not related to that.
3. Only power button work just for forcefully manual power off the machine.

#### Behaviour

1. CPU cooling fan noise and rotate faster as compare to normal Ubuntu 14.04 or any other OS.
2. Screen just freezes, doesn't go black. In Ubuntu 14.04 screen converted into black color and many times Ubuntu recover from hang mode but in Ubuntu 16.04 there is no way to come back from the frozen state.
3. After restart Ubuntu works well but later the same problem occurs.

#### I tried

1. I ran update as well as upgrade commands many times, because many times that solved problems, but this time that trick has not worked.

   sudo apt-get install update upgrade

#### Configuration and Architecture of my Laptop:-

i386
Aspire E15 : E5-511-P7UX
Intel Pentium quad core processor N3530 (up to 2.58 GHz)
Intel HD Graphics
2GB DDR3 L Memory
500 GB HDD.

There is no hardware problem as per my observation because in the same machine when I use any other Operating there is no problem.
I also read these questions:
[ubuntu 16.04. pc Freezes for unknown reason](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859037/ubuntu-16-04-pc-freezes-for-unknown-reason)
[Ubuntu 14.04 randomly freezes on Dell Precision M4500](https://askubuntu.com/questions/467894/ubuntu-14-04-randomly-freezes-on-dell-precision-m4500/467903#467903)

Comment: definitely the c-state bug

Comment: @Zanna how to solve that unknown problem? c-state bug?

Comment: follow the link and see the answer there :)

Comment: @Zanna Ok I will go through that. And mark my question as duplicate.

Comment: start your laptop during booting process press escape key click on Ubuntu recovery mode click on drop on root and try root type apt-get clean for more details click <a href="http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/09/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-using.html"> this link</a>

Comment: no nvidia graphics in laptop

Comment: How much swap do you have set up? In `terminal` type `swapon`, and then `free -h`, and edit that output into your question, and I'll take a look.

Comment: `apt-get clean` deletes cached apt downloads that in no conceivable way could be related to the reported issue. For more information please read the comments under the question and in order to learn more about maintenance commands: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Maintenance_commands

Comment: @heynnema 
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1.9G        1.3G        141M         84M        413M        244M
Swap:          3.8G        428M        3.4G

Comment: Swap if fine. Follow the link to the c-state bug/fix and you should be ok.

Comment: @heynnema I already go through c-state bug/fix but that problem again occur...

Comment: Show me the line from `/etc/default/grub` that includes `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`. Did you remember to `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: @heynnema GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1" also do grub update

Comment: then you rebooted, yes?

Comment: yes! by default

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55382/discussion-between-madhav-nikam-and-heynnema).